# Error occurred in netCDF routine NF90_get_att NetCDF: Attribute not found

Tags: netcdf

I have downloaded the meteorological data in NetCDF format from two different sites. I need to merge two files to put in my ocean model. when running the model with the merged file I got the below error.

```
Error occurred in NetCDF routine NF90_get_att NetCDF: Attribute not found.
```

I think before merging I have to same the attributes of two NetCDF files. but I don't know how to do it. could you please tell me How can I fix this ?
Here is the link that I have shared the two files and the piece of the code. this code is a part of my ocean model that reads the meteorological file.
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GB4VbweJvZrKLkK8rUxBXz1gjVcj_n3N
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetCDF: Attribute not found when merging 2 data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887258/netcdf-attribute-not-found-when-merging-2-data-files)

Comment: You shouldn't ask the same question twice if you (1) don't get an answer, or (2) want to edit your question. That's why they invented the *edit* button :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are reading relative humidity into a variable that seems to be for dew point temperature. This seems to be fundamentally wrong, so please check.

It appears that your code is looking for variable attributes scale_factor and add_offset in all variables. But your rhum variable is stored as percent with no scaling. You could try adding scale_factor=1.0 and add_offset=0 to rhum. To do this, look at the [documentation for ncatted](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncatted-netCDF-Attribute-Editor).

Alternatively, modify the fortran code so that scaling is not used for this variable.

Comment: Dear Robert,   Many Many thanks for your help. The problem has solved. God bless you

Comment: Dear Robert, could you please explain to me how to modify the fortran code so that scaling is not used for this variable? @Robert Davy